# SOSL Problem - Unexpected Results

Tags: rest-api, sosl, parameterizedsearch

I'm doing a parameterized search, but unfortunately I'm getting strange results.

I've added a long text field that, using a flow, is populated with the contents of a group of important fields: Project Name, Organization, Address, Project Description. This works well in a lot of instances.

But there some strange things - for instance, we have an organization called "West Side Campaign Against Poverty". Doing a search for "West Side" returns no results, but doing searches for "West Side Campaign Against Poverty" or "West Side Campaign" or even "Side Campaign" returns all of those expected records.

With the addresses in there, I wonder if the word "West" could be too common in the result set or something like this? But I'm really not sure.

How can I optimize this to get the results I expect?

Comment: Are you adding spaces between the things you're adding to that long text area field? SOSL's tokenization/indexing is primarily looking for spaces (specifically ASCII 0x20) as I learned the hard way a few years back when trying to use SOSL on JSON data I was storing.

Comment: Interesting - I was using a standard space, but then I moved to using newlines between the different fields. But the behavior wasn't any different unfortunately.

Comment: I never found a solution for this, but Salesforce is surprisingly fast when you just do wildcard searches on multiple fields, so I just used that method.